# Routing without reload not working in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

My Employee-Management-Component is reloading when it links to itself with route parameters at interaction and this should not happen. Am I having any issues in my code? The `<p-dropdown>` and `<p-datatable>` are components from primeNG and do what their name says. EventHandlers and properties should also be easy to understand. If not just ask.

```
 import ...

@Component({
selector: 'employee-management-table',
template: `


<div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad" id="CONTENT">

    <nav class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
        <p-dropdown [options]="departments" [(ngModel)]="selectedDeparment" (onChange)="selectDepartment($event)"></p-dropdown>
    </nav>

    <p-dataTable [value]="employees" [(selection)]="selectedEmployees" (onRowClick)="routeToEmployee($event)">
        <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
        <p-column *ngFor="let col of columns" [field]="col.field" [header] = "col.header"></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>

    <employee-form [employee]="employee"></employee-form>
</div>

`,
styleUrls: [],
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, EmployeeFormComponent, Dropdown, DataTable, Column],
})
export class EmployeeManagementTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

private employees: Employee[];
private employee: Employee;
private newEmployee: boolean = false;
private selectedEmployees: Employee[];
private departments: SelectItem[] = [];
private selectedDepartment: string;
private columns: any[];
private paramSub: any;
private employeesSub: any;
private departmentSub: any;


constructor(private employeeManagementService: EmployeeManagementService, 
            private route: ActivatedRoute, 
            private router: Router,
            private ccs: ComponentCommunicatorService,
            private logger: Logger) { }

ngOnInit(){

    this.columns = [
    ....      
    ];

    this.selectedDepartment = this.ccs.getSelectedDepartment();
    this.getDepartments();

    this.paramSub = this.route.params.subscribe(
        //Success    
        params => {          
            if(params['type']){
                let type = params['type'];
                this.logger.log(type);
                if(type === "employee"){
                    if(params['option']){
                        let option = params['option'];
                        this.logger.log(option);
                        this.doEmployeeOption(option);

                    }else if(params['id']){
                        let id = params['id'];
                        this.logger.log(id);
                        this.editEmployee(id);
                    }
                }else if(type === "department"){
                    if(params['option']){
                        let option = params['option'];
                        this.logger.log(option);
                        this.doDepartmentOption(option);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        //Error
        err => this.logger.error(err),
        //Complete
        () => { }
    );
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.paramSub.unsubscribe();
    this.employeesSub.unsubscribe();
    this.departmentDub.unsubscribe();
}


doEmployeeOption(option: String){

    switch(option){
    case 'new':
        this.newEmployee = true;
        this.employee = new Employee();
        break;
    case 'delete':

        break;
    default:
        this.logger.log("Default");
        break;
    }

}

save(){
    if(this.newEmployee){
        this.employees.push(this.employee);
        this.employeeManagementService.insertEmployee(this.employee);
        this.newEmployee = false;
    }else{
        this.employees[this.findSelectedEmployeeIndex()] = this.employee;
    }
    this.employee = null;
    window.history.back();
}

abort(){
    this.employee = null;
    window.history.back();
}

routeToEmployee(event){
    this.logger.log(event.data);
    this.employee = event.data;
    let link = ['/employee-management/employee', this.findSelectedEmployeeIndex()];
    this.router.navigate(link);
}

editEmployee(id: number){
    this.logger.log('edit '+id);
    for (let employee of this.employees) {
        this.logger.log("Edit: "+employee);
    }

    this.employee = this.employees[id];
    this.logger.log('check');



findSelectedEmployeeIndex(): number {

    this.logger.log("Method: "+this.employee);
    this.logger.log("Method: "+this.employees.indexOf(this.employee));
    return this.employees.indexOf(this.employee);
}

selectDepartment(event: any){
    this.ccs.setSelectedDepartment(event.value);
    this.getEmployees(this.ccs.getSelectedDepartment());
}

getDepartments(){

    this.departments.push({label: 'Alle', value: 'all'});

    this.departmentSub = this.employeeManagementService.getDepartments().subscribe(
          //Sucess
          data =>  {data.forEach((item, index) => {
                        this.departments.push({label: item, value: index.toString()});
                    });    
                   },
          //Error
          err => this.logger.error(err),
          //Complete
          () => {this.logger.log('done loading');
                 this.departmentSub.unsubscribe();
                 this.getEmployees(this.selectedDepartment);}
    );
}
getEmployees(department: any){

this.employeesSub = this.employeeManagementService.getEmployees(department).subscribe(
          //Sucess
          data => {this.employees = data},
          //Error
          err => this.logger.error(err),
          //Complete
          () => {this.logger.log('done loading');
                /*for (let employee of this.employees) {
                    this.logger.log("Observable "+employee);
                }*/
                 this.employeesSub.unsubscribe()}
    );
}
```

**ROUTES**

```
export const EmployeeManagementRoutes: RouterConfig = [
{
path: 'employee-management',
component: EmployeeManagementComponent,
children: [
  { 
    path: '',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: ':type/:id',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: ':type/:option',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  },
]
}];
```

Everything gets loaded as wanted but if I click on an employee `routeToEmployee` routes me to `./employee/:employeeArrayIndex`, the page reloads (what it should not) and it crashes in `editEmployee` where I want to assign the selected employee from the employees array to the employee variable that I can display him. 
Error message is `'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'`. The number is for the array index where the employee should be. So I assume the array is empty after the re-init. Only `getDepartments()` gets called again but does not call `getEmployees()` anymore.

Comment: Do you mean the page reloads or the component is re-created instead of reused? How do your routes look like?

Comment: Oh sorry. You described the problem better than I did. The component re-creates itself I think because a part of the ´ngOnInit()´ is re-ran and than crashes totally.  But the routed url is correct, at least something.

Comment: Please add your routes to your question.

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there. Code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: Ok just seen it by myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `, pathMatch: 'full'` to this line `path: '', `

Comment: How is the router supposed to distinguish     `path: ':type/:id'` and `path: ':type/:option'`? I think routes need to differ more than only with parameter names.

Comment: I added `pathMatch: 'full'` still not working. The router is not destinguishing between them. The two routes load the same component I thought I can use the two routes for different parameter names and then decide in my component what to do (see my parameter subscription in the component). I am not sure if that is the proper way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried removing one of these two routes. The router gets an URL and has to decide which route to choose. The URL doesn't contain a parameter name, therefore the router doesn't have any information that allows it to make the decision.

Comment: No difference. The table-component is still re-creating itself and I get the same `cannot read property error` as before.

Comment: I guess you would need to reduce the code to the bare minimum in a Plunker where it can be reproduced. You could try `this.router.navigate([this.findSelectedEmployeeIndex()], {relativeTo, this.route});`

Comment: It is also not working. I will provide a Plunker with the data for you tomorrow ok?  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hello Günter, I have tried to find my error again before making a Plunker for you. It seems that I have found it. I have not initialized the employees array at the beginning of the class. Now it works with the array but can you understand why this was happening? I am really curious about where this came from because the array was never used before getting data from service.

Comment: But if I navigate to my component and click an employee it re-inits the component. But this happens only after the first click event after navigating to the component. All other clicks work as expected.

Comment: Har to tell without a Plunker to reproduce